# Getting failure while making http call from javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services, httpwebrequest, sencha-touch

I am hitting a url over http with GET request. I am using below code.

```
onReady: function() {

        var makeAjaxRequest = function() {


        var myUrl = encodeURI('http://domainname/VW-MAPP/fgnwasxuyu/10548168/2012-04-11 12:42:36/5555');
    Ext.Ajax.request({

        method: 'get',
    url:  myUrl,

    success: function(response)      {     
    alert(''+response.responseText);     
    console.log("response:-"+response.responseText);      },     
    failure: function (response)      {     
    console.log("Failure");    
    console.log("response status:-"+response.status);
    alert("Failure");
}
            });
        };



        new Ext.Panel({
            fullscreen: true,
            id: 'content',
            scroll: 'vertical',
            dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                dock: 'top',
                items: [{
                    text: 'XMLHTTP',
                    handler: makeAjaxRequest
                }]
            },{
                id: 'status',
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                dock: 'bottom',
                title: "Tap a button above."
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

I tried a lot but getting below error

XMLHttpRequest cannot load //URLNAME//. 
Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Please help if any one has any ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried two approaches

(1) Dumped the response.xml to the local domain and access and we got the success.

(2) Disable google chrome security by the command  chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security and were able to hit the url over GET method and got success.

Answer (score 2):

The **Same Origin Policy** is built into the browser and prevents you from making AJAX calls to any other domain other than the one serving up the current page.

If the response is JSON, you can use the JSON-P method, otherwise you need a server-side proxy to make this call.

Comment: Or, if he has to access to the other system, send the proper headers.

Comment: Hi Diodeus, Thanks a lot for the response. Can you please tell me on what to do to avoid this browser behaviour? How can I make the ajax calls to the server?

Comment: With PHP you can use CURL, but I have no idea what you're using as a server.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Sorry for asking silly questions. But does it look like a problem with sending not proper headers?

Comment: I hope you're not actually using "://domainname/"

Comment: @Diodeus: Yes, I am using domain name into my url such as this http://enfotech/mobileservices/services/accountservice/account/VW-MAPP/fgnwasxuyu/10548168/2012-04-11 12:42:36/5555